# private method `update' called for #<Customer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Whenever I try to do an update on my Customer class, I keep receiving that the a private method 'update' was called.

Application trace:

    `` app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:46:in `update' ``

So, in the code it's in this function:

```
 43 def update
     44   @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
     45 
     46   if @customer.update(customer_params)
     47     redirect_to @customer
     48   else
     49     render 'edit'
     50   end
     51 end
```

So, I assume this issue is occurring within my Customer Model, which is:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
       include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection
   attr_accessible :name, :web_address, :notes
        belongs_to :location
        validates :name, presence: true,
                        length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

And then in the view:

```
  <%= form_for :customer, url: customer_path(@customer), method: :put do |f| %>
<div class="well center col-sm-10">
        <legend> Customer: </legend>
        <span class="row">
        <div class = "form-group col-sm-5">
                <%= f.label :name %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :name %>
        </div>

        <div class = "form-group col-sm-5">
                <%= f.label :web_address %> <br />
                <%= f.text_field :web_address %>
        </div>
        </span>
        <span class="row">
        <div class = "form-group col-sm-5">
                <%= f.label :notes %> <br />
                <%= f.text_field :notes %>
        </div>

        </span>

        <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I never defined a private function called update, and I'm not really sure where to begin debugging this.

Comment: Which version of rails are you using?

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.2.16

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use [update_attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes), for Rails versions lesser than 4.

[Persistence#update](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update) was private prior to Rails4

Answer (score -2):

You have a `private` somewhere above where you defined the `update` function. Move the `private` command and all private functions to the bottom of the file, so the private does not apply to the update method.

Comment: While I have a private below this code segment, I do not have a private declaration above this update function.

Comment: what is that `enter code here include ...` line in the model? Could you check if that is not causing the problem? Also, post the view code where update is called (edit.html.erb or _form.html.erb, etc.)